# Use hash value for ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a form from JSON. Every input is described in JSON and I iterate through them and create inputs. I now want to put some data in the inputs, and save this data. I tried using a hash where the keys are the data field name, and the value the value entered by the user.

This is my code:

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="form2" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset id="fieldset1">
        <div class="control-group" data-ng-repeat="item in last_admin.templates" data-ng-show="item.name != 'Default Order'">
            {{create_new_record(item)}}
            <label class="control-label">{{item.name}}:</label>
            <div class="span3 controls" data-ng-switch on="item.type">

                <div data-ng-switch-when="LIST">

                    <select data-ng-model="new_record[item.name]" data-ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in create_options_array(last_admin.templates, item.name)" class="span3"  ></select>
                </div>

                <div data-ng-switch-when="STRING">
                    <input class="span3" type="text" novalidate="" data-ng-model="new_record[item.name]" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>                                  

        <div class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>

        <div class="">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-ng-click="new_data(); $parent.create_form = false;">Save</button>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-ng-click="$parent.create_form = false">Cancel</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

controller:

```js
$scope.new_record = {};
$scope.create_new_record = function(template){
    $scope.new_record[template.name] = "dd";
}
```

The problem is I can't enter anything in the inputs.

Comment: Your indentation is totally off whack.

Comment: I would suggest creating the model (calling create_new_record) inside the controller, and not inside the html markup